# HTTP Request Login to Facebook

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I am trying ruby's rest-client gem to send a login post to Facebook. This is my code, but I can't get logged in to Facebook via Rest Client.

```
require 'rest-client'

response = RestClient.post 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php',
{
    :params => {
            :email => '######',
            :pass => '######',
            :lsd => 'AVrBPjy-',
            :default_persistent => '0',
            :timezone => '',
            :lgnrnd => '071129_XSyy',
            :lgnjs => 'n',
            :locale => 'en_US',
            :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20130331 Firef$
            :content_type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            :referer => 'https://www.facebook.com/'
    }
}

puts "Response Code: #{response.code}"
puts "Cookie: #{response.cookies}"
```

After getting the response cookie, I am trying this functions to get authenticated pages.

```
response2 = RestClient.get 'https://www.facebook.com/zuck/info'
{
    :params => {
            :cookies => response.cookies,
            :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20130331 Firefox'
            :content_type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            :referer => 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php'
    }
}
puts response2.headers
```

The response always includes faulty headers.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to authenticate myself as a registered user, and see each page through rest-client as same as an authenticated user sees it. So far, I can't authenticate myself to Facebook.

Comment: What are faulty headers?

Comment: The second requested page is not rendered as same as authenticated user renders it. The outputs are different.

Comment: Look at your question. You show us what you're trying to do, but you don't show us what the responses are. You just say you get "faulty headers". That tells us nothing. What response code do you get? What error messages? How is the returned page different, and why can't you use it? As is, you're not telling us anything usable.

Comment: **UPDATE**

I am trying to authenticate myself as a registered user, and see each page through rest-client as same as an authenticated user sees it. So far, I can't authenticate myself to Facebook.

Comment: @Yagiz did it work?